# Why isn't my controller taking the param value from the form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, controller, ruby-on-rails-5, simple-form

I've been looking for a solution to this for quite sometime now but I cannot wrap my head around on how to solve this. I'm new to Rails/Ruby programming and would appreciate any direction on this problem.

I have a form that takes in values and creates a Task object. Each Task *belongs_to* a Lead and a Lead *has_many* Tasks.

The path for a new Task takes in the `lead_id` as one of the parameters.

```
/accounts/:account_id/reps/:rep_id/leads/:lead_id/tasks/new
```

But my goal is to also allow the user to use the form to create a Task for any lead. So, ideally, he should be allowed to select a lead from a dropdown and that lead_id needs to travel through to the CREATE method.

Here's my form:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@task, url: account_rep_lead_tasks_path) do |f| %>
<%= f.error_notification %>

<div class="field">
    <div class="control">
        <div class="select">
        <%= f.collection_select :lead_id, @leads, :id, :name %>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="field">
    <div class="control">
        <%= f.input :task_type, required:true, autofocus:true, input_html: {class: "input"}, wrapper: false, label_html: {class: "label"} %>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="field">
    <div class="control">
        <%= f.input :description, required:true, autofocus:true, input_html: {class: "textarea"}, wrapper: false, label_html: {class: "label"} %>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="field">
    <div class="control">
        <%= f.button :submit, class: "button is-primary" %>
    </div>
</div>
```

By default, I render the new Task form for the latest Lead. Suppose the latest Lead created has an ID of 21, here's what shows in the URL:

```
http://localhost:3000/accounts/1/reps/2/leads/21/tasks/new
```

When I submit the form however, even though I'm selected a different lead via the collection_select input in the form for lead_id, the Task isn't being created for the selected Lead but being created for lead with id = 21.

The server logs show that the parameters that are being sent to the CREATE method are:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"sKwctK492JH01yXilEI7jSSmv53ggiJuRBH/9Ate2AS+Lx53CO5BqgIOh44uvhFi6MPJ+Og1EY0U8m2BzqC9eA==", "task"=>{"lead_id"=>"16", "task_type"=>"Hello", "description"=>"Is it me you're looking for?"}, "commit"=>"Create Task", "account_id"=>"1", "rep_id"=>"2", "lead_id"=>"21"}
```

As you can see, there's a lead_id = 16 (which means that the form is taking the input correctly) but also another lead_id = 21 is present for which the Task is being created.

I want the Task to be created for lead_id = 16. Any idea on what I should be doing?

Here's my Task create controller action

```
def create
@account = current_account
@rep = current_account.reps.find(params[:rep_id])
@lead = @rep.leads.find(params[:lead_id])
@task = @lead.tasks.build(new_task_params)
if @task.save
    redirect_to account_rep_lead_task_path(@rep.account_id,@rep.id,@lead.id,@task)
else
    render 'new'
end
end
```

Comment: It depends on what you want to do, I think you are confused because you are getting two `lead_id`. See my answer below https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48739251/why-isnt-my-controller-taking-the-param-value-from-the-form#48739649.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code

```
def create
  @account = current_account
  @rep = current_account.reps.find(params[:rep_id])
  @lead = @rep.leads.find(params[:task][:lead_id])
  @task = @lead.tasks.build(new_task_params)
  if @task.save
    redirect_to account_rep_lead_task_path(@rep.account_id,@rep.id,@lead.id,@task)
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll find `lead_id` under `params[:task]` hash. Like: `params[:task][:lead_id]`

Answer (score 0):

You are getting 2 different `lead_id` because, first, you have url parameter `lead_id` which is defined in your `routes`:

`/accounts/:account_id/reps/:rep_id/leads/:lead_id/tasks/new`

And Second, it is from your form. So if you want to get `lead_id` from your form, you can use:

`params[:task][:lead_id]`

else

`params[:lead_id]` which is defined in your URL Parameter.